# Error when deleting a page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to Ruby on Rails and I am creating a basic blog application.

I am getting the following error when I have confirmed that I want to delete a post/page.

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in
>   PagesController#destroy
>
> Couldn't find Page with ID=21
>
> {"authenticity_token"=>"JjjfnpIn4ogYhLWnbyGHjwLsy6YSgDHL+GZfOqkhSow=",
>   "_method"=>"delete",  "id"=>"21"}

I want the user to be redirected to the listing page when they have deleted the post, I understand that it looks as though problem is with the destroy action in the controller.

My code in there is currently:

```
  def destroy #Destroy action
    @page = Page.find(params[:id]) 
    @page.destroy 
    redirect_to page_url
```

I appreciate any advice on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you're deleting a `Page`, you shouldn't redirect back to it because.. it won't exist

maybe try `redirect_to pages_url` instead of `page_url`

Comment: Thanks! I knew it would be something simple, all part of getting used to Rails I guess.